# Python send variables to thread

Tags: python, multithreading, thrift

I'm trying to create my own threading class in Python2.7. I want it to be able to stop that thread with my own class function. Currently I have something like this:

```
class loop(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, myvar):
    super(loop, self).__init__()
    self.terminate = False
    self.myvar = myvar

  def run(self):
    while not self.terminate:
      do.smthng.useful(self.myvar)

  def change(self, newvar):
    self.myvar = newvar #Doesnt work, in run() my old var is still being used

  def stoploop(self):
    self.terminate = True #Also not working

l = loop(1)
l.start()
time.sleep(1)
l.change(2) #thread still using "1"
time.sleep(1)
l.stoploop() #doesnt stop
```

I've read some posts here about this, but it wasnt what I needed.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
As some of the commenters already stated, this part of code looks like to be really working! Problem is in another place of my project. I've found it, but can't solve it. Maybe some of you could help.

So, my project uses Apache Thrift library and the server is in python. 
Server.py:

```
loo = loop(0)
handler = ServHandler(loo)
processor = serv.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket('0.0.0.0', port=9090)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
server = TProcessPoolServer.TProcessPoolServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
print 'Starting the server...'
server.serve()
```

ServHandler.py:

```
class ServHandler:
  def __init__(self, loo):
    self.loo = loo

  def terminate(self):  #Function that can be called remotely
    self.loo.stoploop() #Doesn't work
```

In above case thread isn't terminated and I don't why. There's no error, object exists, but it sets self.terminate value somewhere else. The object id seems to be the same as well as memory address, but it just looks like object is different although loop **init** function is called only once...

Below is the example, when the loop is terminated successfully. 
ServHandler.py:

```
 class ServHandler:
  def __init__(self, loo):
    self.loo = None

  def terminate(self):  #Function that can be called remotely
    self.loo.stoploop() #Does work!!!!!!

  def create(self):
    self.loo = loop(0)  #Function that can be called remotely
```

When I create loop object remotely, I can terminate it remotely. But it doesn't fit me. There should be a thread created before thrift server is served and multiple users have to be able to change vars/terminate/etc of that thread. How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Comment: What gives you the impression that your code "doesn't work"?

Comment: Honestly, what you are doing sounds like overkill. Although you could use Thrift, there are better and easier ways to do it. Or is there a specific reason not shown above why you plan to utilize Thrift?

Comment: JensG, project is 80% finished and very dependable on Thrift already...

Answer (score 1):

**Not a answer per sae, but a useful debug code for the OP**

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class loop(Thread):
    def __init__(self, myvar):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.terminate = False
        self.myvar = myvar

    def run(self):
        while self.terminate is False:
            print('Run says myvar is:',self.myvar)
            sleep(0.5)

    def change(self, newvar):
        self.myvar = newvar

    def stoploop(self):
        self.terminate = True

l = loop(1)
l.start()
sleep(1)
l.change(2)
sleep(1)
l.stoploop()
print('Final product:',l.myvar)
sleep(2)
print('Is the thread alive:',l.isAlive())
```

Tried your code with some debugging prints, and it's working?
Following code produced:

```
[torxed@archie ~]$ python test.py 
Run says myvar is: 1
Run says myvar is: 1
Run says myvar is: 2        <-- Proves that change() does change `myvar`
Run says myvar is: 2
Final product: 2            <-- Also the global scope knows about the change
Is the thread alive: False  <-- And the thread got terminated as intended
```

However, these are not bulletproof ideas when fetching data or dealing with thread-returns for a number of reasons (even tho i use this method myself from time to time), you should consider using [thread.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) which should be used in combination with `l.toplooop()` like so:

```
l = loop(1)
l.start()
l.change(2)
l.stoploop()
ret = l.join()
```

Also when updating data you should aquire locks on your data so collisions don't occur, have a look at [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) objects.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you need?

```
import threading
import time

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.state = threading.Condition()
        self.variable = 10
        self.paused = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self.state:
                if self.paused:
                    self.state.wait()
            self.do_stuff()

    def do_stuff(self):
        time.sleep(.1)
        print self.variable

    def resume(self):
        with self.state:
            self.paused = False
            self.state.notify()

    def pause(self):
        with self.state:
            self.paused = True


loop = Worker()
loop.start()
time.sleep(1)

loop.pause()
loop.variable = 11
print 'CHANGED!'
loop.resume()
time.sleep(1)
```